# how to make use of subclass in c#

Tags: c#, xna

So Im making tetris and I need to make 7 blocks. The problem is is that I have to copy paste the code in 7 different classes(and then changing the grid) so I thought maybe using subclass would be much easier. The problem is I dont know how to do that.

this is my general block class:

```
public class Block
{
    Color Color;
    const int x = 4;
    const int y = 4;
    bool[,] vorm;

    Texture2D block;
    float FallTimer;
    public bool FallingBlock = false;
    Random Random = new Random();

    ZBlock zBlock = new ZBlock();
    TBlock tBlock = new TBlock();
    SBlock sBlock = new SBlock();
    OBlock oBlock = new OBlock();
    JBlock jBlock = new JBlock();
    LBlock lBlock = new LBlock();
    IBlock iBlock = new IBlock();



    public void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Tetris.inputHelper.KeyPressed(Keys.Down))
        {
            FallTimer = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < blokvorm.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < blokvorm.GetLength(1); j++) ;
                // blokvorm[i, j] += 15;
            }
        }
    }

    public void speed(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        double SpeedCounter = 3;
        int LevelCounter = 1;
        if (LevelCounter < Tetris.GameWorld.level)
        {
            SpeedCounter -= 0.5;
            LevelCounter++;
        }
        FallTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (Math.Round(FallTimer, 1) == SpeedCounter)
        {
            FallTimer = 0;
            //BlockPosition.Y += 15;

        }
    }

    public bool[,] blokvorm
    {
        get
        {
            vorm = new bool[x, y];
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    vorm[i, j] = false;
                }


                    int r = Random.Next(7);
            if (r == 0)
            {
                vorm = ZBlock.zblock();
            }
            else if (r == 1)
            {
                vorm = TBlock.tblock();
            }
            else if (r == 2)
            {
                vorm = SBlock.sblock();
            }
            else if (r == 3)
            {
                vorm = OBlock.oblock();
            }
            else if (r == 4)
            {
                vorm = JBlock.jblock();
            }
            else if (r == 5)
            {
                vorm = LBlock.lblock();
            }
            else if (r == 6)
            {
                vorm = IBlock.iblock();
            }
            return vorm;
        }
    }



    public TBlock TBlock
    {
        get { return tBlock; }
    }
    public ZBlock ZBlock
    {
        get { return zBlock; }
    }
    public SBlock SBlock
    {
        get { return sBlock; }
    }
    public OBlock OBlock
    {
        get { return oBlock; }
    }
    public JBlock JBlock
    {
        get { return jBlock; }
    }
    public LBlock LBlock
    {
        get { return lBlock; }
    }
    public IBlock IBlock
    {
        get { return iBlock; }

    }




    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager Content)
    {
        block = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Block");
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        if (!FallingBlock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < blokvorm.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < blokvorm.GetLength(1); j++)
                    if (blokvorm[i, j])
                        spriteBatch.Draw(block, new Vector2(30 + (i * 15), 30 + (j * 15)), Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

}

So How can I use this class to create other 7 block classes(T, L, I, O etc) easily?

Edit: My block all looks like this:

```
{

    const int x = 4;

    const int y = 4;


    public bool[,] tblock()

    {
        vorm = new bool[x, y];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <y; j++)
            {
                vorm[i, j] = false;
                vorm[0, 1] = true;
                vorm[1, 1] = true;
                vorm[1, 0] = true;
                vorm[2, 1] = true;
            }


        Color = Color.Indigo;
        return vorm;
    }
    public void RotationLinks(InputHelper inputhelper)
    {
        bool[,] nieuw = new bool[x, y];
        if (inputhelper.KeyPressed(Keys.Left))
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; ++a)

                for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b)

                    nieuw[a, b] = vorm[x - a - 1, b];


            vorm = nieuw;


        }
    }


}
```

}

So to make other 6 I copied theh whole code and change the grid value. Is there a possible way to make it easier using bock class?

Comment: sounds like you just need to google `inheritance in C#`

Comment: Haven't you already asked this?

Comment: What I would suggest you is to make use of inheritance as it was just said. But also look for either write a Factory class to generate those blocks.

Comment: _"I have to copy paste the code"_ -- copy/paste what code? The code you posted above doesn't necessarily look ideal, but neither does there appear to be redundancy. As stated, the question is far too broad, because a) Stack Overflow isn't the right forum for an education on use of inheritance, and b) it's not even clear what your _specific_ impasse at the moment is, and so there are too many possibilities for guessing at and addressing that impasse. Please narrow your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.